# How to get name of queue?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have dispatched all my jobs like so:

```
$job = (new \App\Jobs\UserJob($user))->onQueue('users');
dispatch($job);
```

Then, in my `AppServiceProvider.php`, I have put this event listener ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#job-events)):

```
Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event)
{
    //
});
```

How can I get the name of the queue ("users") in the event listener above?

I have tried:

```
Log::info($event->job->getName());
Log::info($event->job->getQueue());
```

But these return:

```
[2016-08-17 19:51:19] local.INFO: Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler@call  
[2016-08-17 19:51:19] local.INFO: default
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel, when using the `Queue::after` event listener, the JobProcessed event does not provide a direct method to retrieve the queue name. However, you can achieve this by accessing the underlying job data within the listener.

Here's an example of how you can get the queue name in your `Queue::after` event listener:

```
    use Illuminate\Queue\Events\JobProcessed;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
    // ...
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
    $payload = $event->job->payload();

    // Extract the data from the payload
    $data = json_decode($payload['data']['command'], true);

    // Check if the job is an instance of your UserJob
    if ($data['command'] === \App\Jobs\UserJob::class) {
        $queueName = $data['data'][0]->queue ?? 'default'; // default is used if the queue name is not present

        Log::info("Queue name: $queueName");
    }
});
```

In this example, we access the job payload and extract the data from it. We then check if the job is an instance of your `UserJob` class and retrieve the queue name. If the queue name is not present, it defaults to '`default`'. Adjust the code according to the structure of your payload and the actual location of the queue name in your job data.